# I am getting problem in speech recognition in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know it is silly question as I am new I am working on notes app I have add speech recognition feature with simply adds text into textview whatever we speak. It is working perfectly but the problem is that when I use second time in same the previous text get deleted and gets new text. I need to get the old text be like that and new text to add after that.

```
This is my speech to text code
layoutMiscellaneous.findViewById(R.id.speechtotext).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                        "Hi Speak Something");
               try {
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 33333);
               } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                   Toast.makeText(CreateNoteActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
        });



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if(selectedImageUri != null) {
                    try {

                        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        imageNote.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        imageNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.imageRemoveImage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        selectedImagePath = getPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);

                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 33333 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            inputNoteText.setText(result.get(0));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```java
inputNoteText.setText(result.get(0));
```

It simply resets the text and then replaces it with your input.

All you have to do is to store the text already inside of it and then append the input.

Something like this:

```java
inputNoteText.setText(inputNoteText.getText()+result.get(0));
```

Your new full code:

```java
//This is my speech to text code
layoutMiscellaneous.findViewById(R.id.speechtotext).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                        "Hi Speak Something");
               try {
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 33333);
               } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                   Toast.makeText(CreateNoteActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
        });



@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if(selectedImageUri != null) {
                    try {

                        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        imageNote.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        imageNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.imageRemoveImage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        selectedImagePath = getPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);

                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 33333 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            inputNoteText.setText(inputNoteText.getText()+result.get(0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have  another question how I can add that drawing pad on text area like we have on notes app of ios?

Comment: @PushkarJain you may only ask one question at a time in StackOverflow, accept my answer with the check mark and ask that question in a new thread. If I answer your question here, then that means I will be an accomplice in breaking a general rule.

Comment: Ok. The answer for previous one worked perfectly. Thank You